# Lookup value for a field in excel table based on condition from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a named excel table (Table1) that has a column which I need to fill based on a simple Vlookup formula from my source data. But the source data was too big and hence I made that into an access table. Now I want my Table1 to find the row in the access table that matches the value in column B in table1 to column 1 in the access table and gets the value from column 3 in access table and populate it into column U in table1. I want this for all the rows in the table. The table in excel is named as Table1 and it updates its row range automatically as more fields are populated below the last row in that table.

I know how to get entire tables from access but not how to get only data from one column and enter it into another column in excel. I am ready to use SQL but don't have much idea about how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I made an access table A, then a linked table B that takes Excel data from a table C. Then a query to take data from both tables and make a new table. Table C in excel is then linked to the query and it updates when i click refresh. It's like a cycle, which is probably not recommended since table C is also a source for the query and also the result, but it works and I don't care.
Thanks!